# WebPack can't executed by command in local projet

Tags: javascript, webpack, visual-studio-code, command-line, command-line-interface

Am a old dinosaur and trying initiate myself to basic webpack by following this tutorial.

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/modern-javascript-explained-for-dinosaurs-f695e9747b70#6c16

But when i trying to execute Webpack , my terminal give me error!!

`./node_modules/.bin/webpack index.js --mode=development`
What am do wrong ?

[image]

I do those step

- Open empty folder project in VsCode
- `npm init -y`
- Create a basic file `index.js` `index.html`
- `npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev`
- then am lock here `./node_modules/.bin/webpack index.js --mode=development` give error

I try many other syntax but alway not bot work !
What am do wrong ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For window, path should not start from `./`

**Correct:**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack index.js --mode=development"
  }
}
```

Comment: thats was not saying in the tutorial ! thanks for the tips. 
Did you have any good tutorial (updated) with vscode maybe for start with webpack?

Comment: haha! it is not the tutorial issue. Logical thing. Understand the diffenence between window and mac(unix). Tutorial wont teach u that.